# Creating ArcGIS Online Organizations account

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

How do I create a ArcGIS Online Organizations account?

We have to two ArcGIS Desktop Basic licenses of the type `Single Use` and should have therewith access to an ArcGIS Online Organizational Account (*if I believe the information of our dealer*).

I found the option to [Request Permissions](https://my.esri.com/#/authorizations) but I don't get it from who and which permissions.

[image]

I got an mail with the content:

> Your Permissions Request Has Been Received
>
> [...]
>
> The request will be reviewed by the administrator of the organization. You will receive an e-mail once your request has been processed.

The content is confusing as I should be already the administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just talked with my dealer and he said that there is a missing connection between the **My Esri Account** and the **ArcGIS Online Account**. They will contact Esri and connect the both accounts.

---

At the end I got an email from Esri with a link for merging this two accounts.